# Powershell: find and replace tag value in xml with the tag name to create sample data

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to find and replace multiple tag values in an xml document with the tag name plus incremented value. The test data I have has a constant value for each string and i want to replace it with the name of the tag that surrounds it and then suffix an incremented value

eg)

```
<CREATE_DT>str1234</CREATE_DT>
<SOLD_TO>str1234</SOLD_TO>
<SHIP_TO>str1234</SHIP_TO>
```

to

```
<CREATE_DT>CREATE_DT_tag_1</CREATE_DT>
<SOLD_TO>SOLD_TO_tag_2</SOLD_TO>
<SHIP_TO>SHIP_TO_tag_3</SHIP_TO>
```

I am thinking this can either be done as a text manuipulation or as an xml parser. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$str = [xml]@"
<DOC>
  <CREATE_DT>str1234</CREATE_DT>
  <SOLD_TO>str1234</SOLD_TO>
  <SHIP_TO>str1234</SHIP_TO>
</DOC>
"@

$i = 1
$str.DOC | Select-Xml -XPath '*' | 
    Foreach {$_.Node.InnerText = $_.Node.LocalName + "_$(($i++))"}
```

Note: the extra parens around $i++ is required to get PowerShell to emit the value of $i in addition to updating the value.